# How does this loop work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I've been trying to work through the Eloquent Javascript textbook and I can't completely understand why this loop works in order to build a list of objects. Here's the code:

```
function arrayToList(myArray) {
    list = null
    for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        list = {value: myArray[i], rest: list};
    }

    return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList[10,20]);
```

Sends out {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

I think its a recursive loop, but I don't see how that properly builds back into a list. All I can see now is the value property of list being assigned the value of myArray[i] and then rest being assigned null.

If someone could explain to me how this loop iterates to build this list, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Give it an array with more than two elements. Maybe this makes it clearer how that works.

Comment: It is not recursive, just in `for` loop you assign old `list` value to new one. First iteration it is `null`, second time it is `{value: 20, rest: null}`.

Comment: I think I get it. I'll keep working on it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is recursive in a way. Look at the value of the property rest in the list object. On every loop iteration, list becomes an object that contains a value plus itself. That's how it creates the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of `for` loop `list` variable is assigned to itself. ***An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand***, which means: right side will be calculated, than it will be assigned to left side.

```
list = null
----------------
for i=1
myArray[1] = 20
list = {value: 20, rest: null}
----------------
for i=0
myArray[0] = 10
list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Comment: I just explained this in a comment but this is a good answer version lol

Answer (score 1):

This function builds a singly linked list with all the elements of `myArray`, by iterating through `myArray` in reverse order (from the last element to the first).

Each item in the resulting list has two properties:

- `value`: the actual value extracted from `myArray`,
- `rest`: which represents all the next items in the list.

The loop itself isn't recursive, but the resulting object is in fact an encapsulation of items (similar to [cons cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) in LISP).

The reason why the loop iterates backwards over `myArray` is that it's much easier to build the linked list that way:  all you need to do is maintain the tail of the list (initially `null`), prepend one element to it, and use the resulting 'augmented tail' as a base for the next iteration, until no further element is available.